# How do I find $\cot[\sin^{-1}(-\sqrt2/3)]$?

Tags: trigonometry

My first problem is finding $\sin^{-1}(-\sqrt2/3)$, since $-\sqrt2/3$ isn't in the unit circle. Hence, I'm not sure how to find the angle.

Then once I get the angle, how do I find $\cot(x)$?

Comment: When it is difficult to find the angle itself, try to determine the dimensions of the reference triangle... e.g. what  is the hypotenuse, opposite, and adjacent sides of a right triangle that corresponds to a 4th quadrant angle? Use that information to determine the cotangent. Drawing a diagram is really helpful.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** $$\cot(\sin^{-1} (x)) = \frac{\cos(\sin^{-1} (x))}{\sin(\sin^{-1} (x))}=\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}$$

Comment: How did you get $$\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}$$?

Comment: @user122965  Note that $\sin(\arcsin x) = x$.  Also, note that if $\arcsin x = \theta$, then $\sin\theta = x$.  Moreover, $\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta = 1$.  Solve for $\cos\theta$, then take the range of $\arcsin x$ into account when determining whether to take the positive or negative root.